# How to close Java Formatter, in finally or not?

Tags: java-6, formatter, finally, resource-leak

I know that normally `streams` and `formatters` (particularly `java.util.Formatter`) in Java should be closed in `finally` to avoid from resource leaks. But here I am a little bit confused, because I see a lot of examples where people just close it without any finally block, especially the formatters. This question may have no sense to some people, but I want to be sure in what I am asking about. 
Some examples from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util/Formatter/Java_Formatter_close_.htm) and from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/formatter_close.htm) where the formatters are just closed without any block.

Please consider that my question is only for Java 6 and lower versions, because I know about try with resources.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  Formatter formatter = new Formatter(buffer, Locale.US);

  // format a new string
  String name = "from java2s.com";
  formatter.format("Hello %s !", name);

  // print the formatted string
  System.out.println(formatter);

  // close the formatter
  formatter.close();

  // attempt to access the formatter results in exception
  System.out.println(formatter);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide an example instead of linking to large code base websites. Which kinds of formatters are you concerned about? There are lots of formatter classes for all kinds of purposes so it would be helpful if you narrow that down.

Comment: @micker thanks for the notice, I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific example, it is not necessary to call `close()`. You only **need** to close the formatter if the underlying appender is `Closable`. In this case you are using a `StringBuffer`, which is not `Closable` so the call to `close()` does nothing. If you were to use `Writer` or `PrintStream`, those are closable and the call to `close()` would be necessary to avoid leaving the stream open.

If you are ever unsure if it is `Closable` it is best to just call `close()` anyway. No harm in doing so.

Comment: Now it is clear, thanks! This was the answer which I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, without further comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  Formatter formatter = null;
  try {
    formatter = new Formatter(buffer, Locale.US);
    String name = "from java2s.com";
    formatter.format("Hello %s !", name);
    System.out.println(formatter);
  }
  finally {
    if (formatter != null) {
      formatter.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My question was, whether there is any specific reason to not close it in finally, because I thought maybe there is some nuance which I would like to know.

Comment: I would prefer to use close() correctly evertime, to get a consistent coding style, also this would avoid errors with future releases of java, for the case that close is required in the future, or for the case that you will work with a derived class that required to close it's resources. Also I would recommend reading Scott Meyers and Herb Sutter - it's not about Java, but about general coding practice.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but again my purpose was just to understand the difference.